# Calling gpg from inside golang changes it's behavior

Tags: go, gnupg

First, I'm using gpg, because openpgp module doesn't support gpg-agent.

My problem:

If, at the command line, I run the following, gpg decrypts the file and writes its contents to stdout (like I want):

```
/usr/bin/gpg --decrypt /home/wwalker/castle_keys.asc
```

So, then, I run it from inside Go, and the behavior changes, it writes to a sibling file to the asc file (I've change the exec'd app to env and run it and the environment is the same as the parent (as expected)).  I don't know if this is a Go thing (I doubt it) or a gpg thing (I expect it to be very wary of where it writes to):

```
wwalker@hatter:~/golang_workspace/src/devops/play$ ./play

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Wayne Walker (Ruby Hacker) <wwalker@redacted.com>"
4096-bit ELG-E key, ID 39D0C3D7, created 2007-12-31 (main key ID A62B624A)

File `/home/wwalker/Files/castle_keys' exists. Overwrite? (y/N) 
Enter new filename: asdf
```

play.go:

```
wwalker@hatter:~/golang_workspace/src/devops/play$ cat main.go
// Author wwalker

package main

import (
        "bytes"
        "fmt"
        "os/exec"
)

func decryptFile(filename string) ([]byte, error) {
        //cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/env")
        var cmd exec.Cmd
        var output bytes.Buffer

        cmd.Path = "/usr/bin/gpg"
        cmd.Args = []string{"--decrypt", filename}
        cmd.Stdout = &output

        if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }

        return output.Bytes(), nil
}

func main() {
        bytes, err := decryptFile("/home/wwalker/Files/castle_keys.asc")
        if err == nil {
                fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(bytes))
        }
}
```

Comment: I have since added ```"--output", "-" ``` to the Args and that "fixes" it but I'm still wondering what the difference is between at the shell and spawned from Go in that same shell environment.

Comment: A lot of programs change their behavior if the output is a tty or not.

Comment: You should remove your email from this question.